# Python: Delete letters in word which occur more than N times consecutively

Tags: python, text

Let's say that I have a sentence:

```
sentence = "Eveeery mondayyy I waaake upp"
```

I would like to create a function which deletes all letters which occur more than N times consecutively in a word.

So, if I say: N = 2
the result should be:

```
result = Eveery mondayy I waake upp
```

How can I do this in an efficient way ?

Comment: Please post the sample of work that you have tried so far, SO is not s coding service

Comment: Efficient: start coding, Show us code that does not work. Inefficient: waiting till SO solves your problem

Comment: your condition "which deletes **all** letters which occur more than N times" is definitely contradicts with your final output. `Eveeery` -> `Eveery` - means "remove" just **one** not **all**

Comment: I will add some code and rephrase my sentence

Comment: @totyped : Yes , better do your homework , before it's turn out cold outside :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub()` solution:

```
import re

def remove_continued_char(s, n):
    pat = re.compile(r'([a-z])(\1{' + str(n) + '})')
    return pat.sub('\\2', s)

sentence = 'Eveeery mondayyy I waaake upp'
print(remove_continued_char(sentence, 2))
```

The output:

```
Eveery mondayy I waake upp
```

---

- `[a-z]` - match only alphabetic characters(letters)
- `\1` - backreference to the 1st captured group i.e. `([a-z])`
- `\\2` - points to the 2nd captured(parenthesized) group value

Comment: Really nice !! Thanks a lot. Would you mind to explain in your answer, how the capturing of group values works  ? I have never used it.

Comment: @totyped, you're welcome. This is basic regex theory https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for the link!

Answer (score 1):

To give you with a good start : 
Just posting a sample which might help you :

```
import re
regex = r"(.)\1+"
test_str = "sentence = Eveeery mondayyy I waaake upp"
# use \\1\\1 if you need to replace with two characters and so on 
subst = "\\1"
# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output :

```
>>>Every monday I wake up
```

Hope this helps

Comment: regex everything?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque : edit : added a comment line above subst to fulfil the condition

Comment: Thank you very much ! Can you explain me what the subst. actually does ?

Comment: @totyped : It substitutes for the occurrence of regex with mentioned substitute , for more please refer https://regex101.com/r/T5jWJn/1

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over the letters of the sentence while keping track of the previous letter, and how many times it was seen.

```
def del_n(n, s):
    so_far = 1
    previous = s[0]
    res = [s[0]]

    for idx, c in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if c == previous:
            so_far += 1
            if so_far >= n+1:
                continue
        else:
            previous = c
            so_far = 1
        res.append(c)
    return ''.join(res)


sentence = "Eveeery mondayyy I waaake upp"
del_n(2, sentence)
```

#### output:

```
'Eveery mondayy I waake upp'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a function without importing any external module:

```
sentence = "Eveeery mondayyy I waaake upp"



def no_dublicate(senten,N):
    final=[]
    for word in senten.split():
        track=[]
        for chara in word:
            track.append(chara)
            if track.count(chara)>N:
                track.remove(chara)


        final.append(track)

    return ' '.join(["".join(item) for item in final])


print(no_dublicate(sentence,2))
```

output:

```
Eveery mondayy I waake upp
```